# Not able to run the Git custom commands from Git bash in windows

Tags: git, bash, shell

I have created a small executable file (git-test) and placed it under `C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin` path.

I have also added the above path in the `Path` environment variable. When I run git test on bash it gives me below error.

```
git: 'test' is not a git command. See 'git --help'
```

Is there anything I am missing here or anywhere I need to paste the file.

Comment: And if you add the '.exe' extension?

Comment: There is no '.exe' file here. I have just create a shell script file with the name pattern as `git-<custom-name>` and tried to access it using git bash. (like the way git flow command works)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My bad!!! While creating the file I forgot to mention the `#!/bin/sh` as first line. When I added this line in my git-test file I was able to run the file from git bash using the command `git test`.

Comment: I came back to give you this advice and already found it ;) Well done! And you could put your file anywhere in the PATH not specially in the git folder.

Comment: Thanks @Philippe! I will also try putting my file in different folders.

Answer (score 0):

Git does not have a `test` command.

If you want to set your own git command you should set [`git alias`](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Git-Aliases).
Gti aliases can be simple commands. multiple commands and even executing a script file.

For example you can see here few simple aliases + some complex ones.
Take a look on the `l` alias. Its alias for a bash script in unix.

In your case create an alias for your test script in the same way.

[image]

Answer (score -2):

`git test` is not a command that git knows, as it's telling you by hinting at the available commands listed by running `git --help`.

To execute that command, type: `git-test` because that's the full command name.

Comment: I am trying to figure out a way how custom commands in git works. The way where you create a shell script file by the name `git-<custom-name>` and call from git bash with command `git custom-name`. I took the example of git flow commands, where I am having all git flow files in `C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin` (e.g. git-flow) and I can execute the script from git bash using the command `git flow`.